# Azure Synapse SQL CICD with multiple environments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse, cicd

Might be a stupid question but seems to be very difficult to find information about Synapse with multiple environments.

We have dev/test/prod environment setup and need to create partially-automated CICD pipelines between those. The only problem is now that we cannot build dynamic SQL scripts to query from the respective storage accounts - so those could be identical no matter the environment. So, dev Synapse using data from dev-storage and so on. Dedicated SQL pool can benefit from Stored Procedures, and I could pass parameters there if it works. But what about serverless pool? What is the correct way?

I've tried to look options from OPENROWSET with DATA_SOURCE argument as well as EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE expression without any luck. Also, no one seems to offer any information about this so I'm beginning to think if this whole perspective is wrong.

This kind of "external" file reading is new to me, I may have tried to put this in a SQL Server context in my head.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Serverless also supports stored procedures and dynamic SQL so give that a try.

Comment: Oh, okay. I missed that one. I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: After you try the methods and think it helpful to you, you can answer the question yourself and mark it as a correct answer so that others who meet the same issue will appreciate your work. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Serverless pool does support both procedures and dynamic SQL, yet you currently cannot call that straight from Synapse Pipelines.

You have to either trigger those procedures via Spark notebooks or by creating separate Synapse Analytics Linked Services for each of your databases in a Synapse Serverless pools and work from there.

Comment: You can call a serverless stored proc from Synapse pipelines - it's just a matter of using the right activity - Stored Proc not 'Sql Pool Stored Procedure' which is only for dedicated SQL pool as far as I can tell.